# Where to start with Hyperledger Fabric Development?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am pretty new to Hyperledger fabric and try to understand what all topics I need to learn so that I am able to create one full application.

Like for Ethereum , I followed below steps.
1. Setup Ethereum development environment.
2. Used the solidity language to develop the smart contract and used remix as beginner to create smart contract.
3. Use of Truffle Framework for development, testing etc.
4. deploy the smart contract to blockchain either from remix or using truffle framework.
5. Use Web3 to access that smart contract function deployed on blockchain from front end.

Please help me with me similar steps for Hyperledger Fabric.

I heard about lot of terms like composer, modeling language, ACL, Scripts files under that. I also heard about Go language and SDK there.

My understanding is that, first of all Hyperledger Fabric need to be setup on the local system that I am able to do and next step is do the development of DAPP.

One option to that development is by using Hyperledger composer but I dont see use of Go language there. So I wanted to know if composer if the only option to do the development or we have any other way.

Comment: if you want to start with a new tech, the first place to go is their documentation. Hyperledger has good docs and tutorials. it sounds like you need to start with the basics: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/

Answer (score 2):

**Hyperledger Compose**r is a tool, that simplifies application development on top of the **Hyperledger Fabric** blockchain infrastructure.

If you are interested in the blockchain infrastructure, start with the Fabric [tutorials](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#).

If you are interested in blockchain applications, start with the Composer [tutorials](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/tutorials.html).

The Fabric tutorials includes the development in to way:

You can use either **Go language** to write chain code or you can use **composer language**.

You can try both.

There is also Fabric Java SDK available for building Java client applications that interact with the blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you at first to deploy a first hyperledger network in localhost (use docker-compose). You can help yourself with the fabric-sample https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.

You must understand the mechanisms of transactions (proposal, endorsement etc.) the roles of each component.

After that learning to deploy a chaincode, learn the development of GO chaincodes linked to hyperledger fabric.

Then you can approach the hyperledger SDK (NodeJS or Java).

Answer (score 1):

Start with Hyperledger Composer, its a hyperledger fabric building tool: (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/introduction/introduction.html)

Composer allows you to experiment and play around with Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain through an online web interface. No need to jump into core building blocks when using Composer. The language used is mostly javascript / yml based so its easy to pick up.

Next step is to work directly with Hyperledger Fabric. But by the time you would have gone through Composer that will be your decision.

About the languages used, Hyperledger Fabric blockchain can be setup using GO, Node or Java.

Comment: I would be VERY happy to start learning from Composer. But... Composer has been put on pause. https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/composer/message/125 Do you think it still worth to start learning Fabric via Composer? I hope so because atm I'm having hard times learning Fabric (and Sawtooth as well).

Comment: I also wonder if I can port a Composer app to native Fabric at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

as a start you can try hyperledger composer which is tool made to accelerate the implementation of your blockchain application  smart contracts, ACL to your participant so to understand whats going on pleas follow the documentation in the following [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/introduction/introduction.html)

and you will find this online [composer playground](https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/editor) very helpful to get your hands on implementation and test your application flow then you can export your application file as .bna file and deploy it on your hyperledger fabric framework.

after that you have to install the prerequisites for hyperledger localy which you can find in the following [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html)

after that you have to decide the type of fabric your going to use will it be single organization fabric which will use solo messaging server to handle synchronization between order peer and your peer.However, you can use multi organization fabric to be your framework which rely upon kafka and zookeeper to manage state between your multi orders and deploy your application.However, you can find [node fabric SDK](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/) to manage your hyperledger fabric.

Comment: Thanks for your reply so at high level below steps you are recommending. 1. Use playground to start with where build one test case 2. setup hyperledger fabric locally But my question is that where we need to use GO language as composer use modeling language.

Comment: You don't need to use GO at all there is NodeJS SDK to run all these process

Comment: "after that you have to decide the type of fabric your going to use". which types of fabric do exist?

Comment: if it's multi organizations fabric or single organization fabric.